# PowerShell and ActiveDirectory module - Find Users that are not members of particular groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

In the last week, I have come across PowerShell and ActiveDirectory for the first time. I would like to be able to find a list of users that aren't Admins or Domain Admins.

So far, I know how to get all the properties for all ActiveDirectory users with the following command/statement:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties *
```

What I would like to do is to print out just the usernames of current ActiveDirectory users - that are not Admins or Domain Admins.

Here is some pseudocode/Powershell code of what I am trying to do:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties *
foreach($u in $users){
    if ($u isn't an administrator OR $u isn't a domain administrator){ 
        Write-Host "User Name:" $u.Name
    }
}
```

When I run the `Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties *` command, I am seeing the `MemberOf` property for each user - which I'm thinking may be a clue. I have also heard of `AdminCount` from various sources found via Google (is there something called `DomainAdminCount` ?).

I have been asked specifically to not use the PowerShell extension for ActiveDirectory - even though various sources say having this extension will make it easier.

I have spent about 2 hours testing various combinations of statements, but my novice PowerShell status isn't helping me too much. I would be grateful for any assistance, and some clear explanations behind any feedback.

Comment: I understand requirement to check membership in Domain Admins group, but have no idea what you mean by Admins - such group does not exist (not by default) in AD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's pretty easy task and you do not need to retrieve all users first and loop:

```
$DomainsAdminsDn = (Get-ADGroup 'Domain Admins').DistinguishedName
Get-ADUser -Filter { -not (memberof -eq $DomainsAdminsDn) }
# OR
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!(memberof=$DomainsAdminsDn))"
```

You can do the same with any other group.

**EDIT**:
Reversed queries, to return account that are **not** in group(s). BTW, this won't work:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter { memberof -ne $DomainsAdminsDn }
```

It will skip over all accounts that are not members of any other group than default one.

Comment: Thanks for the help BartekB :) I also tweaked the code below and it gets exactly what I was hoping for:

## This variable gets all the users that are Domain Administrators
$DomainsAdminsDn = (Get-ADGroup 'Domain Admins').DistinguishedName

## This variable gets all the users that are Administrators
$AdministratorsDn = (Get-ADGroup 'Administrators').DistinguishedName

## This line will get all the users that are not "Domain Administrators" or "Administrators"
Get-ADUser -Filter {(memberOf -ne $AdministratorsDn) -and (memberOf -ne $DomainsAdminsDn)}

Comment: How can I get group `CN=ROLE_AGENT,OU=PROFILES,OU=NSI PRODUCTION,DC=xxxxx,DC=net` ?

Comment: @Kiquenet as you already have DN, you can move to `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter` part and replace `$DomainsAdminsDn` with your string.

Answer (score 1):

I used a little bit of what you everyone contributed, and tweaked it. I needed to find out who wasn't apart of a group, and I only needed their name. Let me know if this helped you out.

```
$Internet_Users = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like "Internet_Users" }
Get-ADUser -Filter { -not (memberof -eq $Internet_Users) -and (enabled -eq "True" -and objectclass -eq "user")} |Select Name | Export-CSV "C:\Users\YOURNAME\Documents\Enabled_Users_Without_Internet_Users_Group.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

With some very helpful feedback from BartekB, I was able to achieve the solution below:

```
## This variable gets all the users that are Domain Administrators
$DomainsAdminsDn = (Get-ADGroup 'Domain Admins').DistinguishedName

## This variable gets all the users that are Administrators
$AdministratorsDn = (Get-ADGroup 'Administrators').DistinguishedName

## This line will get all the users that are not "Domain Administrators" or "Administrators"
Get-ADUser -Filter {(memberOf -ne $AdministratorsDn) -and (memberOf -ne $DomainsAdminsDn)}
```

For the last line, I wanted to combine the two variables to make the filtering more specific (i.e look for users that are not Administrators OR Domain Administrators). I had to spend about 10 minutes digging around for the PowerShell equivalent of the && operator - which was just as I suspected.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that "Domain Users" is handled specially, so if you try to find people not in that group it won't work.

Based off code from:
http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/find-users-not-in-a-group/

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -Properties MemberOf, PrimaryGroup
$dugDn = (Get-ADGroup "Domain Users").DistinguishedName
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    Write-Verbose "Working on $($user.Name)"
    $groups = $user.MemberOf, $user.PrimaryGroup
    if ($groups -NotContains $dugDn)
    {
        Write-Host "$($user.SamAccountName) not in the domain users group"
    }
}
```