# PowerShell export AD users not in specific group + attributes

Tags: powershell, active-directory, extract

I need to do an AD export with the info below:
- all enable users NOT present in a specific group
- email address
- account name

and export everything into a csv file

Can u help me please?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: I searched Google for ["powershell active directory find enabled users in a group"](https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+active+directory+find+enabled+users+in+a+group) and found some relevant results. You can also search for ["powershell export list to csv"](https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+export+list+to+csv).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell and ActiveDirectory module - Find Users that are not members of particular groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353414/powershell-and-activedirectory-module-find-users-that-are-not-members-of-parti)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
$group = 'my group name'
$GroupMembers = Get-ADGroupMember $group -Recursive
Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq '$true'" -Properties Mail |
    Where-Object { $_.SamAccountName -notin $GroupMembers.SamAccountName } |
        Select-Object SamAccountName,Mail | 
            Export-Csv Output.csv -NoType
```

`Get-ADGroupMember` with the `-Recursive` switch will recursively retrieve AD objects that are a member of `$group`.

`Get-ADUser` utilizes a filter to only query enabled users. Notice that you must add the `Mail` property because email address attributes are not in the default display. You can tweak this filter to make the query faster. If you are willing to add a little complexity and do performance testing, it may be faster to build separate `Get-ADUser -Filter ...` queries than relying on `Where-Object`. Performance will depend on your AD size and how many members are in the target group.